# How to read SMS using AT on an embedded system with limited memory?

Tags: memory, sms, embedded, at-command

I'm developing a piece of embedded software, which also communicates with a modem through the AT protocol. Now I want to read messages, but I have come across a problem with my memory capacity. It could be that there are multiple messages for me, and using the AT command set, I get them returned all at once. I do not have the memory capacity to store them all to process them (I only have 1KB or so).

See the examples here:
http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/receivesmsat/

I send `AT+CMGL="ALL"`. I then get back something like:

```
+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+31625012354",,"07/07/05,09:55:16+08"
Test message 1
+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+31625012354",,"07/07/05,09:56:03+08"
Test message 2

OK
```

The problem here is that the message can contain certain directives, which trigger certain actions, which might take a while to execute. During that time, the buffer for receiving data from the modem can (will) overflow. On the other hand, I do not have the memory capacity to first read ALL the messages into memory to prevent the buffer overflow, and then process them from memory.

An alternative is reading a single message, with `AT+CMGR=2`, getting back just one message:

```
+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+31625012354",,"07/07/05,09:56:03+08"
Test message 2

OK
```

However, for this to work, I need know the storage location (2 in the above example).

My gut feeling tells me to first run `AT+CMGL`, parsing the data and only keeping the storage locations, then requesting and parsing (and deleting) them one by one with `AT+CMGR`.

However, I would like to receive a second opinion. I'm not that experienced with AT nor with embedded software yet, so perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 4):

Send `AT+CMGL="ALL"` and save the first message up to the return.  Ignore all other data until you receive `OK`, indicating that the modem is done.  After processing the first message, delete it by sending `AT+CMGD=<NUM>` (where  is the number of the first message). Repeat.

Yes, it's kind of ugly, but it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is an unsolicited message that may be configured for newly received SMS messages.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423308/what-is-the-best-design-for-polling-a-modem-for-incoming-data) for a bit more information on configuring the system.

Whenever you receive the `+CMTI` message the index field (the number at the end of the string can be used when reading the message, just pass this value to the `AT+CMGR` command to get the latest received message.

I would recommend deleting older (used) messages as most embedded type modules only have very limited memory for storing messages.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that I use. Send `AT+CPMS` to read how many messages are stored in the SIM internal memory and what is the capacity (number of messages) of the memory.

If `AT+CPMS` reports there is one or more messages waiting in the memory, send `AT+CMGR` starting from position 1. You will end with one message (maybe at position 2 or 10) that you can receive and parse.

After processing it, delete it with `AT+CMGD` (now you now what is its position).